# How can I successfully wait for this intercept in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a testing route in my application that sets up a user's session. I'm creating the following command, `login`:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('login', (attributes = {}) => {
  cy.intercept('**/_testing/session/new').as('session')
  cy.request('post', '/_testing/session/new', attributes)
  cy.wait('@session')
})
```

However, whenever running my tests, `cy.wait()` times out.

[image: Failed cy.wait() command]

I have confirmed in the console that my [minimatch](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Matching-URL) pattern passes.

[image: Successful minimatch]

What do I need to do for `cy.wait()` to detect my `intercept`?

Comment: Will increasing the timeout for this specific end point help ?

Comment: The timeout is 5000ms. When I inspect the request in cypress I see the correct response inside the "Yielded" response and the duration is < 200ms.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding, but it looks like you are trying to intercept the `cy.request()`, which is not possible - see [intercept - Notes](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept.html#Notes)

> **cy.intercept() cannot be debugged using cy.request()**
>
> cy.request() sends requests to actual endpoints, bypassing those defined using cy.intercept()
>
> The intention of cy.request() is to be used for checking endpoints on an actual, running server without having to start the front end application.

You basically just use the request response as the intercept

```
cy.request('post', '/_testing/session/new', attributes)
  .then((resp) => {
    expect(resp.status).to.eq(200)
  })
```

or just wait for an on-screen artifact that happens after the login.